# How to generate n threads in clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure, pmap

I am wondering how to create n threads in clojure. There is a function named "estimate-value", which can estimate a value and return the result.
Now I want to use pmap or pcalls to create n threads and each thread can compute an estimate value, then combine the n results and return the final estimate value. 
My code is

```
(defn compute-value [n]
    (/ (apply + (pmap (estimate-value) (range n))) n))
```

I am sure the function estimate-value is true. But when I run and got an error:

```
user=> (compute-value 3)
ClassCastException java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  clojure.core/pmap/fn--6744/fn--6745 (core.clj:6729)
```

How can I fix this compute-value function? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at `pvalues`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine, beside a little problem,

```
(pmap (estimate-value) (range n))
```

This first evaluates `(estimate-value)` once, which I assume returns a `double`, and then it tries to use that `double` as a function to `pmap`, which is the error you are seeing `java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`.

You simply need to wrap that in a function, like so:

```
(pmap (fn[x](estimate-value)) (range n))
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify whether `estimate-value` is pure or not, but wouldn't it make more sense to assume that it is? In which case, wouldn't it be `(fn [x] (estimate-value x))` or just `estimate-value`?

Comment: It seemed that `estimate-value` takes zero parameters, otherwise we would have seen a `ArityException` instead of a cast to IFn.. However, I agree with you that if indeed `estimate-value` takes a single numeric parameter, a simple `(pmap estimate-value (range n))` would have been simpler.

Comment: @Shlomi Your explanation is very clear and now I know where the problem is. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Shlomi Ah, very astute! Thanks for explaining.